# Gatsby error, I am getting the 404 page with error saying that there is no page at this URL until I refresh the page again

Tags: reactjs, navigation, gatsby

I am getting the 404 error page when I navigate to a page saying that there is no page with this URL until I refresh the browser the page then shows.

I tried using @reach/router to navigate instead of react-router-dom so now the navigation works but this error keeps coming. I restarted the app few times, the navigation works perfectly at first then this error starts to occur.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a different library for routing, which is not the case when working with Gatsby. The way Gatsby works is that you need to create a `.js` file inside a pages folder, and it will automatically become a route.

If you want your page rendered at `<host-name>/HelloWorld, then you need to make a file in pages named` HelloWorld.js.`